# help me to solve this Cryptarithm problem

Tags: cryptarithm

Hello I tried various things but ain't getting where to begin, if anybody would let me know how to solve this it will be of great help

> P X B * W Y A
>
> ---
>
> O A Z O
>        O N X W+
>    O X N P  + +
>
> ---
>
> O A N Z N O

Comment: Which of PXB and WYA is on top in the usual arrangement of a pencil-and-paper multiplication? Also, you should have six digits in the product, not five.

Comment: Googling for the letters in this problem online suggests that the product should be "O A N Z N O", not "O A N Z O".

Comment: Are different letters supposed to represent different numbers?

Comment: @Mark: That’s the convention, yes.

Comment: sorry ya my bad... ya 1 letter is 1 digit and every letter has a unique number and also the letter 'O' is not zero(0)

Comment: We still need to know which of PXB and WYA is the multiplier and which is the multiplicand.

Comment: PXB is MULTIPLICAND and WYA is multiplier

Answer (score 1):

By brute-force enumeration of all permutations of ten digits, I have found two solutions which match the `PXB * WYA = OANZNO` constraint:

```
418 * 709 = 296363

295 * 164 = 048380
```

However, for none of these the intermediate expressions are fulfilled.

I guess, the task is to prove a contradiction rather than to find a solution.